# Observable collection not getting retrieved from isolated storage settings in WP7 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am storing the observable collection in my application isolated storage settings. The list is getting saved successfully during the application exit. But when I launch the application again its not able to find the stored key from the isolated storage.

Here is my code

```
    void LoadSettings()
    {
        if (settings.Contains("DiaryItems"))
        {
            diaryItems = (ObservableCollection<MyDiaryItem>)settings["DiaryItems"];
        }
    }

    void SaveSettings()
    {
        settings["DiaryItems"] = diaryItems;
    }
```

I am calling `SaveSettings` method during my application closing and application deactivated.

I am calling `LoadSettings` method during my application launching and application activated.

When I was debugging I could see an error saying that

> 'settings["DiaryItems"]' threw an exception of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'

Just wondering what could be wrong with the settings. The same code works for a simple list of type List.

Answer (score 2):

Actually when you want to store any items in the IsolatedStorage you  have to call the save of ApplicationSettings function

so modify your save function as follows,

```
void SaveSettings()
    {
        settings["DiaryItems"] = diaryItems;
        settings.Save();
    }
```

Sorry i forgot to mention you that , your MyDiaryItem, should be properly serializable.

Comment: really strange that it seems to work for normal list without giving settings.Save();

Comment: yes I used  settings["DiaryItems"] = diaryItems;
            settings.Save();

Answer (score 2):

Note sure why it doesn't work, but you can try to wrap your ObservableCollection inside of a list:

```
void LoadSettings()
{
    if (settings.Contains("DiaryItems"))
    {
        diaryItems = new ObservableCollection<MyDiaryItem>((List<MyDiaryItem>)settings["DiaryItems"]);
    }
}

void SaveSettings()
{
    settings["DiaryItems"] = diaryItems.ToList();
}
```

You need to have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file, or the 'ToList' won't work.

Comment: actually I found the real problem behind. The observable collection is getting stored to isolated storage when the application exits. But when I m trying to fetch the list from isolated storage its empty. Dont know why the list is not getting fetched from isolated storage

Comment: Do you have the same problem with your other settings, or only with the ObservableCollection?

Comment: cant figure out where is the problem coming from. It should be either the way I m storing it to isolated storage or else it should be either the way I tried to fetch it. Are there any other solution to store Observable collection to isolated storage which could help

Comment: Yes I have tried your code but still I m not able to fetch the stored list from isolated store properly.

Comment: void LoadSettings()
        {
            if (settings.Contains("DiaryItems"))
            {
                diaryItems = new ObservableCollection<MyDiaryItem>((List<MyDiaryItem>)settings["DiaryItems"]);
                
            }
        }

        void SaveSettings()
        {
            
            settings["DiaryItems"] = diaryItems.ToList();
            settings.Save();
        }

Comment: I think you'll find valuable information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330991/why-is-isolated-storage-not-persisting-in-my-wp7-application

Comment: I tried to mention the data contract for MyDiaryItems like below but its saying cannot serialise the MiniDiary.MyDiaryItems as its not public. But I have mentioned my class as public only.

Comment: [DataContract]
    public class MyDiaryItem
    {
        [DataMember]
        string entryNotes = "";

        [DataMember]
        string entryDate = "";

        [DataMember]
        string entryLocation = "";

        [DataMember]
        ImageSource entryImage;

    }

Answer (score 0):

try to add your data in dictionary using Add function 
like

```
isolatedstorege.Add(key,value);
```

this way it adds the value [more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.add%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)